# Post request returns dictionary with empty list

Tags: python, http-post

In an attempt to subtract some data from a website with python.
Im not getting the same response as show in the developers window in the browser.

The preview code is the browsers returns:

```
{$id: "989"...}
$id: "989"
rows:[{$id: "990",constructionId: 84, constructionUnitId: Null,...}]
0: {$id: "990",constructionId: 84, constructionUnitId: Null,...}
1: {$id: "991",constructionId: 108, constructionUnitId: Null,...}
2: {$id: "992",constructionId: 157, constructionUnitId: Null,...}
3: {$id: "993",constructionId: 186, constructionUnitId: Null,...}
```

The response im getting in python:

```
{'$id': '990', 'rows': []}
```

The code im using is:

```
Obj_req = s.post('https://########.com/api/v1/Projects/GetDetailedTree', json=data, headers=headers)
    Obj_req_js = Obj_req.json()
    a = json.loads(Obj_req.text)
    print(a)
```

How can I get a list of the constructionId in this dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending some informations to server. For example bad user-agent or missing some "protection variable headers".

Next thing is you are missing cookies generated on website load.

I can't comment so i post answer.